# Eejrcicio con objetos literales

Tags: javascript

tengo un error en un ejercicio que no logro darme cuenta cual es.
La consigna es
**Para este ejercicio contamos con un objeto literal deportista ya definido, que tiene los siguientes atributos: nombre, energia, experiencia.
Queremos poder pedirle al deportista que entrene. Para esto, nuestro trabajo va a ser completar la función entrenarHoras.
La función entrenarHoras tiene las siguientes tres características:
Recibe por parámetro la cantidad de horas.
Resta a su energía (this.energia) la cantidad de horas x 5.
Incrementa su experiencia (this.experiencia) la cantidad de horas x 2.
Una vez definida la función, podemos ejecutar el código y ver cómo va variando la energía y experiencia del deportista por consola.**

y el ejercicio presenta esto predefinido:

```
let deportista = {
    energia: 100,
    experiencia: 10,
    nombre: "Aimar",
    entrenarHoras: ???
};

console.log("==Antes de comenzar entrenamiento==");
console.log("Deportista energia: "+deportista.energia);
console.log("Deportista experiencia: "+deportista.experiencia);
console.log("==ENTRENANDO==");
deportista.entrenarHoras(5);
console.log("==FIN ENTRENAMIENTO==");
console.log("Deportista energia: "+deportista.energia);
console.log("Deportista experiencia: "+deportista.experiencia);
```

y la modificacion que le hago es esta:

```
let deportista = {
    energia: 100,
    experiencia: 10,
    nombre: "Aimar",
    entrenarHoras: 6
};
    function entrenarHoras(entrenarHoras,energia,experiencia) {
    this.entrenarHoras=6,
    this.energia=energia-entrenarHoras*5
    this.horario=entrenarHoras*2


}

console.log("==Antes de comenzar entrenamiento==");
console.log("Deportista energia: "+deportista.energia);
console.log("Deportista experiencia: "+deportista.experiencia);
console.log("==ENTRENANDO==");
deportista.entrenarHoras(5);
console.log("==FIN ENTRENAMIENTO==");
console.log("Deportista energia: "+deportista.energia);
console.log("Deportista experiencia: "+deportista.experiencia);
```

el error que me da es que **deportista.entrenarHoras is not a function**

Comment: entrenarHoras tiene que ser una funcion, no un valor ;)

Answer (score 2):

Para que el código cumpla con la consigna, debes tratar estos puntos:

- entrenarHoras expresado como función: debe recibir el valor de horas.
- En lugar de modificar this.horario deberías modificar this.experiencia
- Cuando modificas energía, deberías modificar this.energia, para referirte a la energía de ese deportista.
- La función entrenarHoras recibe el valor de horas. El resto de variables las podemos calcular allí.

## Código funcionando

```js
let deportista = {
  energia: 100,
  experiencia: 10,
  nombre: "Aimar",
  entrenarHoras: function(entrenar) {
    this.energia -= entrenar * 5;
    this.experiencia += entrenar * 2;
  }
};


console.log("==Antes de comenzar entrenamiento==");
console.log(`Deportista energia: ${deportista.energia}`);
console.log(`Deportista experiencia: ${deportista.experiencia}`);
console.log("==ENTRENANDO==");
deportista.entrenarHoras(10);
console.log("==FIN ENTRENAMIENTO==");
console.log(`Deportista energia: ${deportista.energia}`);
console.log(`Deportista experiencia: ${deportista.experiencia}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Solo para marcar los errores que veo, tratar de explicarlos y
> comentarte sobre parametros predeterminados y contexto ya que la
> respuesta que te dieron es muy limpia y valida

```js
let deportista = {
  energia: 100,
  experiencia: 10,
  nombre: "Aimar",
  entrenarHoras: 6
  /*
  Si definis la funcion aca si
  el contexto de this es el adecuado porque
   invocas con deportista.entrenarHoras(5)
   como comentario adicional actualmente
    the function keyword no es necesario
entrenarHoras(horas){
  modifica al objeto
    this..........=........
  }
   */
};
  /*

solo envias  un parametro entonces utiliza 
Parámetros predeterminados de función los cuales permiten 
que los parámetros con nombre se inicien con valores
 predeterminados si no se pasa para ellos a ningún valor 
 en el ejemplo aunque no necesario doy valor por defecto a horas 
*/
function entrenarHoras(horas=6,
  energia=100,
  experiencia=10) {
     /* el uso que haces de this es  incorrecto no modificas
      nada del objeto
      console.log('uso incorrecto de this:',this.entrenarHoras,this.energia) undefine 
      */
deportista.entrenarHoras=horas
deportista.energia=energia-horas*5
deportista.horario=entrenarHoras*2
}
console.log("==Antes de comenzar entrenamiento==");
console.log("Deportista energia: "+deportista.energia);
console.log("Deportista experiencia: "+deportista.experiencia);
console.log("==ENTRENANDO==");
entrenarHoras(5);
console.log("==FIN ENTRENAMIENTO==");
console.log("Deportista energia Ahora si se modifica: "+deportista.energia);
console.log("Deportista experiencia: "+deportista.experiencia);
console.log("modifica horas: "+deportista.entrenarHoras);
```

Answer (score 0):

aca te dejo un ejemplo con clase y metodos, todas las respuestas anteriores completan bien tu desafio, solo agrego esta información para desarrollar mas el tema .

```js
class Deportista {
  constructor(nombre, energia, experiencia) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.energia = energia;
    this.experiencia = experiencia;
  }

  entrenar(horas) {
    console.log("==ENTRENANDO==\n")
    let resultadoEnergia = this.energia - horas * 5
    if (resultadoEnergia >= 0) {
      this.energia = resultadoEnergia;
      this.experiencia += horas * 2;
      console.log("==FIN ENTRENAMIENTO==");
      return this.stats()
    } else {
      return `El deportista no tiene energia suficiente para entrenar ${horas} ${horas>1?"horas":"hora"}`;
    }
  }

  stats() {
    return ` Energia: ${aimar.energia}\n Experiencia: ${aimar.experiencia}\n`;
  }
  descansar(horas){
    this.energia +=  horas * 5;
    this.energia = this.energia>=100?100:this.energia;
    return  `El deportista ahora tiene ${this.energia} energia`
  }
};

function entrenar(horas) {
  console.log("==Antes de comenzar entrenamiento==");
  console.log(aimar.stats());
  console.log(aimar.entrenar(horas))
}

function descansar(horas) {
  console.log("Descansando");
  console.log(aimar.descansar(horas))
}

let aimar = new Deportista("Aimar", 100, 30)
```

```html
<button onclick="entrenar(1)">Entrenar Aimar 1 hora</button><br/>
<button onclick="entrenar(5)">Entrenar Aimar 5 horas</button><br/>
<button onclick="entrenar(10)">Entrenar Aimar 10 horas</button><br/>
<br/>
<button onclick="descansar(1)">Descansar Aimar 1 horas</button><br/>
<button onclick="descansar(5)">Descansar Aimar 5 horas</button><br/>
<button onclick="descansar(10)">Descansar Aimar 10 horas</button><br/>
```